# Does React component as a single variable renders faster than memoized component?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to understand, if simple react component without any props, that has been created as

```
const x = <div />
```

will be rendered in a more efficient way during tree comparison than memorized component?

```
const y = React.memo(<div />)
```

Comment: use React Memo if your component will render quite often.

Comment: You didn't understood the question. I need to know, if React.memo does some additional performance issues during the rendering. From my understanding memo has to look somewhere, and get component or invoke create a new component and then rerender. If I use constant as a component, react can just compare references.

Comment: @KalinovskyKonstantin Perhaps your question isn't clear at all? It's not even a proper syntax, because `memo` expects a React component, not JSX. Also the test cases are unclear.

Comment: I've made and example.
Does Constanted will be rendered faster and more efficient than MemoizedMovie
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-demo-forked-y35c7m?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will be rendered in a more efficient way during tree comparison than memorized component?

There's no one good answer to that, because it depends on the case. If a component does not include any heavy logic, it's pointless to wrap it with `memo` because wrapping with `memo` uses memory and slows down your performance a bit.

In your particular example that you have shown in codesandbox, there's clearly no point to wrap your component with `memo` since there is not any complex logic inside.

And once again - in your particular case `memo` is pointless and will run slower than the component without `memo` (because the built-in *shallow comparison* of props has to take place). However, the differences in performance will be practically **unnoticeable**.